# I'm trying to join two tables on three columns and it won't compile due to running out of memory

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join two temporary tables on three different columns, but it won't compile due to the following error:

```
Error Code: 2008. MySQL client ran out of memory
```

This is the query that I'm trying to run:

```
select b.ParentStatus, a.* 
from temp_tblProviderDetails a
inner join temp_tbltblSubmissionStatus b
on a.State_100 = b.StateAbbreviation and
    a.DemoRateYear_101 = b.DemonstrationYear and
    a.ServiceType_102 = b.ServiceType;
```

I attempted to index the tables using the following but it still won't work:

```
CREATE INDEX idxSubmissionStatus ON temp_tbltblSubmissionStatus (StateAbbreviation, DemonstrationYear, ServiceType);
CREATE INDEX idxProviderDetails ON temp_tblProviderDetails (State_100, DemoRateYear_101, ServiceType_102);
```

What can I do to get this query to run? Thanks

Comment: Some metrics would be nice also the result of an EXPLAIN..Also are temporary tables really necessary sample data and expected output would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data you have, you could try to limit the results to e. g. 500 rows. By splicing the results into multiple chunks, you could slowly iterate over the results.

```sql
select b.ParentStatus, a.* 
from temp_tblProviderDetails a
inner join temp_tbltblSubmissionStatus b
on a.State_100 = b.StateAbbreviation and
    a.DemoRateYear_101 = b.DemonstrationYear and
    a.ServiceType_102 = b.ServiceType
limit 500;
```